# Implementing gesture on a marker.iconView in swift 3 and google maps for ios

Tags: swift

I've got a google map and i'm setting marker.iconView to a custom UIView.

```
marker.iconView = customUIView()

func customUIView()-> UIView 
{
  var theView:UIView
  theView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  
 #selector (self.popAction(sender:)))
        theView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}
```

The UIView is pretty much just a textbox and when the UIView is clicked I won't a popup happening from popAction.

But I can't get the gesture functionality to work and I wonder if it's because the gesture is being registered on the google map and not on the UIView.

**** Update *****
After reading the google docs i'm pretty sure i can't add a gesture to a marker.iconView because the UIView is just a "snapshot"

Instead i'm implementing GMSMapViewDelegate.

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        print("markerTapped")
        return true
    }

This function works but what i'd like to do is pass data from my UIView that is the marker.iconView into the above func mapView and not entirely sure how.

### update

So marker.iconView = customUIView(sport: sportEvent) and each sportEvent object has title, date and description. The customUIView looks like a textbox with the info.

There is a loop through an array so that each marker on the map has  specific sportEvent info.

Ideally, I'd like to add a gesture to the customUIView so that when the "marker" is clicked an alert pops up with the details of sportEvent title, date and description. But the way google renders marker.iconView means user input is lost from the customUIView so I can't set a gesture on it.

So i'm looking for a workaround where I can get a particular marker clicked and then an alert pops with that sportEvent info.

So I used GMSMapViewDelegate and then when the marker is clicked func mapView fires. That's cool but I can't get the sportEvent info associated with each particular marker.

So I tried to pass the sportEvent object into func mapView but then the function doesn't seem to execute and the marker is no longer clickable.

Thx.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to pass into the mapView? in the `didTap` method you have access to the `mapView` object. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Hi Simon. Thanks. I have written an update in the text above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I approached it was creating a custom [GMSMarker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker). This will create the points on your mapView.

You want to pass in your `sportEvent` object when initializing the custom marker (i.e. something like `CustomMarker(with: sportEvent)`)

The `GMSMarker` object has some properties you can set which you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker) but, some of the notable ones include:

`title`, `snippet` (text beneath title) which is what you want to set from your sportEvent object.

So, in your custom marker you can do:

```
Class CustomMarker: GMSMarker {
    var title: String
    var desc: String
    ...

    init(with sportEvent: SportEvent) {
       // do some validation before setting this assumes all values are set correctly
       self.title = sportEvent.title //(assuming `.title` is a string)
       self.desc = sportEvent.description
       ...
       super.init()

       title = self.title
       snippet = self.desc 
    }
}
```

Note that the custom GMSMarker may need a `position` property set which is just a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` i.e. (`position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: sportEvent.latitude, longitude: sportEvent.longitude)`

This will by default show you a mini marker info window with your sportEvent object.

If you want to further customize the marker info window you can take a look at [markerInfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#ad925926feb3cec4fbccfd05935876281)

It returns a view if it exists. What I did was create my view programatically and I passed in my custom marker into the view and set everything accordingly there.

Like so:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    let customMarker = marker as! CustomMarker
    return myCustomView(with: customMarker)
}
```

Where `myCustomView` is a method that returns a UIView`

```
func myCustomView(with customMarker: CustomMarker) -> UIView {
    // Set view programatically here with your customMarker
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thx! Just to confirm if I wanted an alert or pop to contain the info from self.title & self.description I should be able to access those properties from the customMarker that is passed into myCustomView? I think that works.